# Mysql: Disk is full error

Tags: mysql, diskspace

I have some problem with my mysql server.

```
120310  6:55:36 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './virtual/cdrs.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  6:59:14 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/lib/mysql/virtual/recordedcalls.MYI' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:05:36 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './virtual/cdrs.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:09:14 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/lib/mysql/virtual/recordedcalls.MYI' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:15:36 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './virtual/cdrs.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:19:14 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/lib/mysql/virtual/recordedcalls.MYI' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:25:36 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './virtual/cdrs.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:29:14 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/lib/mysql/virtual/recordedcalls.MYI' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:35:36 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './virtual/cdrs.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
120310  7:39:14 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/lib/mysql/virtual/recordedcalls.MYI' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
```

When i do `df -h`  it return me

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             221G  124G   86G  60% /
/dev/sda1              99M   23M   72M  24% /boot
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

it means there is enough disk space available still my log says disk is full..

my `/tmp` contain a file `mysql.log`  its size is more than 22GB and still increasing.

Comment: `df` may not show the actual, correct used size as it somehow does not take into account currenctly opened/used files. Hence, that output is not to be fully trusted. Have you tried stopping the mysql server and checked the free size afterwards?

Comment: @DaDaDom i have stop mysql and then add `df -h`
`Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`

`/dev/sda3             221G  126G   84G  60% /`

`/dev/sda1              99M   23M   72M  24% /boot`

`tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm`

Comment: What about a `df -i`? See also http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45111 , there may be some hints there.

Comment: @DaDaDom `df -i`
`Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on`  
`/dev/sda3            59703296   96023 59607273    1% /`  
`/dev/sda1              26104      47   26057    1% /boot`  
`tmpfs                 217667       1  217666    1% /dev/shm`

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with quota limit on mysql user. See here a similar [question: Mysql Disk is full writing](http://serverfault.com/questions/126461/mysql-disk-is-full-writing)

Comment: @ypercube yes i saw this but i don't know how to do quota on this.

Comment: Can you run `quota -q` ?

Comment: @ypercube `quota -q` return nothing.. :(

Comment: I have checked my messages log and found bellow error.

Apr 19 03:29:23 sip3 setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing the mysqld from using potentially mislabeled files (/var/lib/mysql/virtual/sip_buddies.MYD). For complete SELinux messages. run sealert -l 6f302229-578c-4a4d-a854-08349de7f11b