# Why mysql not enough disk space even if any disk is not full?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have following  mysql (5.5.30) error records in nginx (`nginx/1.1.19`) error log:

> [error] 14184#0: *19429717 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (my_table); waiting for
>   someone to free some space" while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: example.com, request: "POST
>   /foo/bar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:
>   "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/foo/bar"

But why? I have enough space and inodes:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        204G   34G  160G  18% /
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  308K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
cgroup           16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        496M   41M  430M   9% /boot


$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md2       13565952 412662 13153290    4% /
udev            4108219    509  4107710    1% /dev
tmpfs           4110672    401  4110271    1% /run
none            4110672      1  4110671    1% /run/lock
none            4110672      1  4110671    1% /run/shm
cgroup          4110672     10  4110662    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1         131072    233   130839    1% /boot
```

Memory consumption is also good:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      32885380   20726092   12159288          0     650556   18127824
-/+ buffers/cache:    1947712   30937668
Swap:     16768892          0   16768892
```

In the same time i have script that updates records and writes some files on disk (pictures) – they throws no errors.

Where could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is it worth providing details on what operation you are doing? (i.e. is it failing to insert or could it be disk consumed as swap on a large query). Also, where in your filesystem are your data files located?

Comment: Have you also seen [this question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223363/mysql-disk-is-full-error?rq=1) comments and notably the link to the mysql bug (no answers though I'm afraid).

Comment: Yep, i've seen this question but there is no answer provided ): `quota -q` not installed on my ubuntu server. Problem exists when i try to insert something in database (updating is ok). But disk is not full (see df in question), even inodes.

Comment: It's strange that problem solved after `service mysql5-server restart`. What was happen? RAM was enough (my database is small and not gzipped dump is about 70 megabytes).